# How to create layout with two not equal columns with Bootstarp

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I create layout like on this picture:

[image: My layout]

I cannot use `.container-fluid` because content have fixed width, but I need background color of each column to be spread to the full page width as in the picture.

Comment: check out bootstraps col offsets. [BOOTSTRAP GRID System](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Comment: columns inside your columns ?

Comment: For example, column with class ".col-lg-3" have background #ffffcc. I don't know how can I colour all free space on the right the same colour of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need some workarounds and some thourough understanding of Twitter Bootstrap. Try this HTML (Twitter Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row nav">
    <div class="container">nav</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row gradientbody">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 gray"><br />col1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 lightgray hidden-md-down"><br />col2</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row lightgray hidden-lg-up">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 lightgray">col2</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.gray {background: gray;}
body, .lightgray {background: lightgray;}
.nav {position: absolute; z-index: 9; background: lime; width: 100%;}
.gradientbody {
background: gray; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, gray 50%, lightgray 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, gray 50%,lightgray 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 50%,lightgray 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='gray', endColorstr='lightgray',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gradientbody > div > div > div {height: 100vh;}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .gradientbody {background: gray!important;}
  .gradientbody > div > div > div {height: auto;}
}
```

See for the Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeoeWx

If you want to use Twitter Bootstrap 3, use the HTML below (you can use the same CSS):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row nav">
    <div class="container">nav</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row gradientbody">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 gray"><br />col1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 lightgray visible-lg"><br />col2</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row lightgray hidden-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 lightgray">col2</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```